# Total Space or Used space on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need a way to get Total Space and or Used space on the device using C# on Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT apps.

I was able to get the Free Space on the device using the below piece of code.

```
var retrivedProperties = await folder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { "System.FreeSpace" });
var dataSize = (UInt64)retrivedProperties["System.FreeSpace"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess we can only get the Freespace from the device using the below code. I researched a lot and gave up and had to live with Freespace

```
var retrivedProperties = await folder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { "System.FreeSpace" });
var dataSize = (UInt64)retrivedProperties["System.FreeSpace"];
```